# Eclipse on MacOS giving multiple different errors

Tags: mac, eclipse, error-logging

I'm a Mac user that's been trying to start Java through Eclipse after some time away from the program. I've been able to restart it and overcome most of the bugs through Google Searching and Stack Overflow, but I've found an error that I could not find much about.

When I open Eclipse, I am either greeted by the welcome menu or this error. In the former case, the error usually pops up after a few seconds:

```
'Tip of the Day. Layout Shell' has encountered a problem.

An internal error has occured.
```

[image: Menu]

[image: Error]

In either case, I cannot open any window/perspective. For instance, clicking `Window > Show View > Project Explorer` simply does nothing - no error message pops up, but nothing else appears.

Trying to do other functions (I clicked Run in this case) results in another error message popping up:

[image: No recent launches]

There appear to be a wide variety of visual glitches as well. Double clicking `Task` in the upper right caused everything but that window to turn gray:

[image: gray]

Additionally, the following error pops up frequently - sometimes after clicking on something and sometimes spontaneously:

[image: Error3]

With all of these errors, clicking `Details >>` simply causes the error window to refresh. I've tried changing workspaces and restarting eclipse with little success. Can anyone help me figure out what is going on and how I might fix these issues.

Comment: From the way you describe the situation sounds to me that your Eclipse installation is clearly borked. My inclination is just remove and reinstall - but I'm not an Eclipse specialist. I would drop also to Stack Overflow, I'm pretty sure someone there has experienced similar problems in the past. Just for clarity I'd add my Eclipse version and screenshot of `Apple / About This Mac`; just the `Overview` tab for starters. If you do ask in SO, please delete this question as cross-posting is frowned upon.

Comment: What version of Eclipse? Older versions of Eclipse have problems on macOS 11. Eclipse 2021-09 runs fine on macOS 11.